# Removing whitespace created while Adding elements (when we delete Elements) in XML

Tags: c#, xml, c#-2.0

I am Adding Some 3  elements to Root element using (We are using .Net 2.0)

```
xnode.AppendChild(parentINode);
xnode.AppendChild(config.CreateTextNode("\r\n"));
//then removeing all added elements using 
xnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xnode);
```

This Will Add a whitespace, I want to remove whitespace that were addedd by adding elements, while removing the childnode.

My original file looks as below:

```
  <c123:Places State="Mine">
  <!-- Names-places -->
 </c123:Places>
```

We will Be adding some elements to it :

```
    <c123:Images State="mine">
     <!-- Names-Places -->
     <Name place=11111>
     <Name place=22222>
     </c123:Places>
```

Then we will delete elements :then it looks as below

```
   <c123:Images State="Mine">
   <!-- Names-Images -->


    </c123:Images>
```

Here we are getting number of white spaces equal to number of elements added, we want to remove/Avoid the white space created after deleting child nodes.

Thanks & Regards,
Channabasappa M

Comment: I Did Just Traversing to XML tag then Removed whitespace with checking //Removing whitespace created 
                if (xnode.NextSibling != null && xnode.NextSibling.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Whitespace)
                {
                    xnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xnode.NextSibling);
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Did Just Traversing to XML tag then Removed whitespace with checking

```
    //Removing whitespace created 

   if (xnode.NextSibling != null && xnode.NextSibling.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Whitespace)
      {
            xnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xnode.NextSibling);
      }
```